# VB.net : Wait a bit before right clicking

Tags: vb.net, cursor, mouseevent

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Cursor = New Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle)
    Cursor.Position = New Point(800, 500)

    'mouse_event WaitFor2 seconds??? 

    Cursor.Position = New Point(800, 500)
    mouse_event(&H8)
    Cursor.Position = New Point(800, 500)
    mouse_event(&H10)
End Sub
```

I am trying to make the cursor wait a few seconds before right-clicking. I've searched and found some complicated solutions that are not exactly what I want to do.

Can this be done with a simple mouse event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what mouse_event is doing, but you should be able to use a Timer to wait for 2 seconds. Add a Timer to your form (for example by dragging one from the Toolbox onto your form in the designer. and then use this code.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Cursor = New Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle)
    Cursor.Position = New Point(800, 500)

    Timer1.Interval = 2000
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Cursor.Position = New Point(800, 500)
    mouse_event(&H8)
    Cursor.Position = New Point(800, 500)
    mouse_event(&H10)
    Timer1.Stop()
End Sub
```

Comment: Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" Alias "mouse_event" (ByVal dwFlags As Long) 
    'LEFTDOWN = &H2
    'LEFTUP = &H4
    'RIGHTDOWN = &H8
    'RIGHTUP = &H10
    'MIDDLEUP = &H40
    'MIDDLEDOWN = &H20